# NextJS using React's Context API with a layout component wrapper

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-context

My setup is as following. I have a layout component where I add a navigation component and children. I wrap them with my Provider like this

`AppLayout.js`

```
<Layout>
  <Navigation/>
  <main>
    {children}
  </main>
</Layout>
```

Now the `<Navigation/>` component has access to the data returned by `React.useContext(ContextProvider)`.
However a child component of Layout does not! If I try to `console.log(state)` in the `<Navigation/>` component I get back the actual data as expected.

But when I have a child component like this:

`Child.js`

```
<AppLayout>
 <div>Some content</div>
</AppLayout>
```

The state is always undefined. The only way I managed to solve this issue was by wrapping the Provider around the Component in the `_app.js` file. Does anyone know how to solve this without wrapping the provider around the `<Component/>` from `_app.js` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible.
Every component that should have access to one context MUST be descendants of THE SAME context provider.

If you put the context provider inside a wrapper component, and this wrapper component is used in multiple different positions, each instance has a separate context provider, which is a different state. That just does not work.

If you do not want your context provider to be in _app.js, then you may put it inside any child component, but still every component that wants to use the state has to be a descendant of the context provider.

e.g.:

```
<App>
    <NoDoesNotHaveStore />
    <ContextProvider store={ myStore }>
        <YesDoesHaveStore />
        <YesAlsoDoesHaveStore />
    </ContextProvider>
</App>
```

You may wrap the context provider:

```
const SomeWrapper = function(props){
    return <ContextProvider store={ myStore }>
       { props.children }
    </ContextProvider>;
};

<App>
    <NoDoesNotHaveStore />
    <SomeWrapper>
        <YesDoesHaveStore />
        <YesAlsoDoesHaveStore />
    </SomeWrapper>
    <NoStoreAgain />
</App>
```

But not multiple times:

```
const SomeWrapper = function(props){
    return <ContextProvider store={ myStore }>
       { props.children }
    </ContextProvider>;
};

<App>
    <SomeWrapper>
        <HasStoreA />
    </SomeWrapper>
    <SomeWrapper>
        <HasDifferentStoreB />
    </SomeWrapper>
</App>
```

Also note that in Next.js, under certain circumstances, the store might be different on server side vs. client side, or on first render vs. clicking a Next-Link.